# jQuery slideToggle animation shifts other elements

Tags: jquery, css

When I click on the element I've registered as the trigger for the slideToggle, the element ticks a few pixels to the right for seemingly no reason. I assume it has to do with the CSS somewhere, but I cannot identify the problem.

Here is a working example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmyGq/ . When 'Advanced Search' is pressed it will tick slightly the right and then back to its original position when clicked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `<a>` element is not a block element, try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZmyGq/2/)

Comment: Ahh interesting. Thank you. What about the display style makes this work?

Comment: jQuery changes the display property of the elements when they are animated from none to block etc. What happens is the `<a>` elements display property is momentarely changed and it moves a little bit. Just setting it specifically to `block` in the CSS fixes the problem. The `<a>` element is not originally a `block` element like for instance a `div`.

Comment: Thank you. The element looks a bit off center now? The offset that was happening seems to be permanent. Any idea how to correct this?